# Javascript method call with a new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, affix

I am setting up JavaScript function call on page load:

```
$('.myMenu').affix({
        offset: {
            top: value
        }
    });
```

After some user interaction the `value` getting changed and at the same time I am calling the code above again expecting that `affix()` will be processing with a new `offset` value, but it is not, it is still processing with initial `value` what was on page load.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        $('.myMenu').affix({
            offset: {
                top: value
            }
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.myMenu').affix({
            offset: {
                top: value
            }
        });
    });
```

Why it is happening? may be some one could explain?
The windows resize triggering on windows resize I make sure that by using `alert` function

I am using `affix()` that is in the twitter bootstrap `3.0` and also I have the same problem with http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav plugin

```
$('.mainNav').onePageNav({
        currentClass: 'active',
        scrollOffset: offsetValue
    });
```

`onePageNav()` not applying a new `offsetValue` if I do `onePageNav()` on screen resize like above in case of `affix()`.

Comment: Where are you calling it ? How are you calling it. Put the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Most plugins provide separate methods for initial attachment to an element (with initial settings) and subsequent changes to those settings.

The precise methods for the latter depend on how the plugin author wrote the code, and indeed whether changes to settings will even be noticed.  If (s)he followed the jQuery UI convention it would be:

```
$('.myMenu').affix('options', { top: value });
```

To get a better answer, provide a link to the particular "affix" plugin you're using, or check its documentation.

Comment: Should it be `$('.myMenu').affix('options', { offset: { top: value } });` ?

Comment: @sreginogemoh no, the bad news is that the Bootstrap affix plugin doesn't have an API method to change the options.  For a nasty hack you can potentially alter `$(element).data('bs.affix').options.offset`

Comment: and what abut `http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav` does it have the API to change options?

Comment: trying to `$('.myMenu').data('bs.affix').options.offset = value` - getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined `

Comment: Well, I did say _potentially_, based on a quick reading of the source code.